# StaleElementReferenceException in datepicker

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am able to select date, day and year from date picker, but after selecting, the page is refreshed and the Webdriver element is detached and getting StaleElementReferenceException. I am not understanding how to build the object instance as its a date picker, it cant be clicked again.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement dateWidget = getDriver().findElement(DATEPICKER_WIDGET);
    List<WebElement> rows = dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

    for (WebElement row : rows) {
        List<WebElement> columns = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        for (WebElement cell : columns) {
            try{
            if (cell.getText().equals(String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)))) {
                        cell.findElement(By.linkText(String.valueOf(dayValue))).click();
                boolean flag = commonpage.isAlertPresent();
                if (flag == true) {
                    String text = commonpage.closeAlertAndGetItsText();
                    addScreenshot("Alert text: " + text);
                }
                break;
                }}catch(StaleElementReferenceException e){

                }
```

The problem is after picking the correct date, I got an alert box and that too handled perfectly. But after alert box, the page is refreshed, and selenium is having problem in identifying what is cell (WebElement) as the page is refreshed. Not understanding how to re-instantiate WebElement cell.